# Can a .net web application pass uncaught exception messages to browser in plain text?

Tags: .net, json, debugging, exception

I'm debugging. on an ASP.net MVC 4 web application.

There are a number of JsonResult Controller Actions in the application.  In the event of an error, the system returns the text of the error and the stacktrace with HTML markup.  This is convenient when the error occurs on a ViewResult Controller Action, but it makes it difficult to read error messages for JsonResult Controller Actions, as I usually see the text of the error message in a debugger, if at all.

Is there a practical way to make the JsonResult Controller Action return its error message to the browser in plain text?

Comment: It seems obvious but.. catch the exception and send the text as a Content or Json result?

Comment: Yes, but I would have to do that on each function individually.  I would like to make it happen globally.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways of handling this, but I suspect the most easy to get working is to catch the exceptions and handle them within the context of your action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        // Your code which may throw an exception.
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.ToJsonResult();
    }
}
```

You can easily create an extension method to perform exception conversion in whatever fashion you like.

```
internal static ExceptionHelper
{
    public static JsonResult ToJsonResult(this Exception ex)
    {
        // TODO: build and return the JsonResult from the exception informtation.
    }
}
```

Whilst it would be nice to handle this in a global fashion, there's no easy way to know what the result of your action was supposed to be without changing its signature in some way that could be reached via reflection.

Comment: If you'd like a more complicated solution that could be applied globally, I can add another answer.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to see your global solution.  I thought it may be possible to do something with the global.asax file, but I was wondering if I was overlooking something that Microsoft provided with the framework.

Answer (score 0):

A somewhat complex solution is to create a custom [`HandleErrorsAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) implementation which you can then add to individual actions, whole controllers or register in your collection of global filters to handle all requests this way. This is the extension point in MVC for custom handling of exceptions.

Your implementation could be something very simple like this:

```
public class HandleErrorsAsJsonAttribute : HandleErrorsAttribute
{
    public HandleErrorsAsJsonAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
        {
            return;
        }

        var ex = filterContext.Exception

        // TODO: build the JsonResult from the exception information.
        filterContext.Result = new JsonResult();

        // Indicate the exception is handled 
        // to prevent it being passed to other filters.
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

In this case you can apply it just to the actions or controllers you want to return information as JSON objects. If all your controllers return JSON, then you can just add the attribute to the global collection and be done with it.